# Missing Tomcat plugin in Intellij 2017.3

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

After applying the fix via the suggestion posted at
  [1]: [IntelliJ IDEA: Tomcat 8.5.13 and 9.0.0.M19 — Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354676/intellij-idea-tomcat-8-5-13-and-9-0-0-m19-error-during-artifact-deployment-s)**strong text**  I'm not seeing the Run/Configurations configuration for Tomcat local/remote in the list.  Note that it is still available and enabled via Settings - Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying this fix for IntelliJ IDEA you should use the Tomcat version that already has this bug resolved. To restore IntelliJ IDEA functionality revert the fix by [reinstalling the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html).